# I am trying to do a simple jersey restful webservice hello world but its not working. Can anyone check where I am doing wrong?

Tags: java, rest, servlets

my web.xml file :
**Web.xml**
I am trying to do a simple jersey restful webservice hello world but its not working. Can anyone check where I am doing wrong?

I am using the below URL :

http://localhost:8080/learning1/rest/firstRest/User1

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Learn</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.java.learning1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Learn</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My restfulwebservice java file : **java file**
Server is responding with HTTP Status code 404 : not found

```
package org.java.learning1;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

@Path("/firstRest")
public class firstRest {

    @GET
    @Produces("MediaType.TEXT_HTML")
    @Path("{name}")
    public String sendResponse(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @PathParam("name") String name){
        String greeting = "hello";
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: The @Produces annotation does take a String but use either MediaType.TEXT_HTML or "text/html".  What you have would not be understood.  I don't know for sure that that is your only issue but it is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello user7481861 and welcome to stackoverflow!

You have two errors in your code, I've corrected them bellow and added a comment in each, saying what was wrong.

```
package org.java.learning1;

//import javax.websocket.server.PathParam; <-- incorrect import
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;   // <<-- correct import
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

@Path("/firstRest")
public class firstRest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML) // No quotes like stdunbar said in the comments 
    @Path("/{name}") // missing slash before name
    public String sendResponse(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @PathParam("name") String name){
        String greeting = "hello " + name; // concatenate the string with the variable name
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional information the slash "/" isn't mandatory in this case though before the parameter.

Comment: @pabrantes, it is working fine now. Thanks. How can I print the value I got through the html URI i.e "name" in the above code.

Comment: @user7481861 just edited the answer to do that as well. Basically you have to concatenate (join) the string hello with the variable you receive.

Comment: @pabrantes, It is not working. parameter that I am passing is not getting displayed on the UI. Below is the URL I am using. http://localhost:8080/learning1/rest/firstRest/java

Comment: @user7481861 got caught in the copy paste :-) your PathParam import is incorrect. You do not want the one regarding websockets but the one regarding javax.ws... I've editted the answer to correct that